Compile a PIE ELF program with different offsets in different sections
I am working on a research project where I need to compile a program with multiple sections. These sections need to be loaded with different PIE offsets. I am wondering how I can do it in GCC.
See below for a MWE. In my program there is a .my_region section and other sections (.text, .bss, ...). I want to make sure that all sections can be loaded at random addresses. Also, I want to make sure the relative offset between .my_region and other sections are different.
For example, this is what I am looking for:



Run number
&my_array
&start
&normal_array




#1
0x01000000
0x00040000
0x00040120


#2
0x06000000
0x00040000
0x00040120


#3
0x0a000000
0x00080000
0x00080120



I think technically this can be implemented either using GOT or the .rela.dyn section. However, I don't know how to pass arguments to GCC and ld to achieve this.

Minimal working example (MWE):
a.c:
int normal_array[10];

int my_array[10] __attribute__(( section(".my_data") ));

void start() {
    normal_array[0] = 0;
    my_array[1] = 1;
    asm volatile("hlt");
}

l.lds:
ENTRY(start)

MEMORY
{
  all (rwxai) : ORIGIN = 3M, LENGTH = 1M
  my_region (rwxai) : ORIGIN = 5M, LENGTH = 1M
}

SECTIONS
{
  .my_data : {
    *(.my_data)
  } >my_region =0x9090
}

Makefile:
CFLAGS = -fPIE
ASFLAGS = -fPIE

# I am on 64-bit x86 Linux platform.
a: a.o l.lds
    ld -pie --dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -T l.lds -o $@ a.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o a

Use make a to compile. Use gdb a to debug (set a break at start and then step through each instruction).

I don’t think the kernel will cooperate. IIUC the kernel only has a single base address for the executable, and it does all of the relocations relative to that base. You could get two (independent) base addresses by loading part of the binary as a shared library, but that’s about it.

I also don’t understand your MWE. The resulting binary isn’t PIE, at least on my machine; it always gets loaded at 0x2ff000. The offset from my_region to all will always be a constant 0x200000.
